# Terminating match at multiple space in Regex Pattern

Tags: regex

I am reading a text which is like this:

```
BROKER : 0012301 AB ABCDEF/ABC

VENDOR NUMBER:  511111                                    A/P NUMBER: 3134

VENDOR  NAME: KING ARTHUR  FLOURCO INC                    OUR  INVOICE #: 553121117   DATE: 05/03/2021
```

I want to extract the field Vendor Name, Vendor Number. Hence I'm using the regex

> (?<=:\s).[^\s]*

But this helps me to extract any field which doesn't have any white space. However, the fields having spaces in between aren't extracted properly like Vendor Name. How do I modify my regex pattern to fetch all fields? I've tried `(?<=:\s).[^\s\s]*` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to match either VENDOR NAME or VENDOR NUMBER and capture what follows until the first encounter of 3 whitespace chars.

Note that `\s` can also match a newline.

```
\bVENDOR\s+(?:NAME|NUMBER):\s+(\S.*?)\s{3}
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bVENDOR\s+(?:NAME|NUMBER)` A word boundary to prevent a partial match, 1+ witespace chars and then match either NAME or NUMBER
- `:\s+` Match `:` and 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\S.*?)` Capture **group 1**, Match a non whitespace char followed by as least as possible chars
- `\s{3}` Match 3 whitspace chars

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DMHL6g/1/).